# How to block wp-admin scanner using IPtables

Tags: debian, iptables

I used the following command to drop connection matching the string wp-login

```
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 70 --algo bm --string 'GET /wp-login' -j DROP
```

I am getting error Line 1 failed. What I am doing wrong with my Debian 9?

Comment: Why don't you use fail2ban?

Comment: I have logging disabled so I cannot use fail2ban.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, fixed it using the following code.

```
*filter
-N wpadmin
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --algo bm --string "wp-login" -j wpadmin
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --algo bm --string "wp-admin" -j wpadmin
-I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --algo bm --string "wordpress" -j wpadmin
-A wpadmin -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Now all the connections are correctly being dropped using the keyword wordpress.